# Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cors, xmlhttprequest

I am facing following problem

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict_home_price' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
  function onClickedEstimatePrice() {
    console.log("Estimate price button clicked");
    var sqft = document.getElementById("uiSqft");
    var bhk = getBHKValue();
    var bathrooms = getBathValue();
    var location = document.getElementById("uiLocations");
    var estPrice = document.getElementById("uiEstimatedPrice");
  
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict_home_price"; //Use this if you are NOT using nginx which is first 7 tutorials
    //var url = "/api/predict_home_price"; // Use this if  you are using nginx. i.e tutorial 8 and onwards
  
    $.post(url, {
        total_sqft: parseFloat(sqft.value),
        bhk: bhk,
        bath: bathrooms,
        location: location.value
    },
    function(data, status) {
        console.log(data.estimated_price);
        estPrice.innerHTML = "<h2>" + data.estimated_price.toString() + " Lakh</h2>";
        console.log(status);
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to add CORS headers to the response coming back from wherever `url` is pointing to.

Answer (score -2):

The error is rather self explanatory... and the question is a duplicate (not the only one, I think).

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it just explains the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I believe that redirection to answer is an answer. MDN links are for education reasons. Hard to tell whether you are right or I am, but I had no bad intentions. This is still a form of helping.

Comment: That's true, however I'd refer you to the Meta question on this subject: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/162238